# Cannot update an IAtomicReference using an IFunction

Tags: hazelcast

I am new to hazelcast, I am using it to distribute a custom data structure, a bloom filter implementation in particular. Since the filter can get quite big I decided to use an IFunction for the updates. The problem I am facing is the following: I am executing an alterAndGet() on the bloom filter reference with which I change its BitSet values. I do get back the new updated filter as I expected but the reference itself is not updated. I looked a bit in the Hazelcast code and I saw that the implementation is using equals() to decide whether or not to update the reference value. I have checked that the returned bloom filter and previous one do not satisfy the equals, so I would expect it to have been updated. Does anyone have an idea on what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you create a unit tests that verifies the problem?

I wrote a big part of the functionality. So if it is broken, I'll fix it. If we do need something to meet your needs, and it isn't too much work, I probably can add it.

Comment: Actually I see what the problem is: My object has a BitSet and its equals depends solely on the BitSet equality. Since I do not want to create a new BitSet every time I get the existing one and update it but since it is the same reference its equals returns true. In the code I see that the reference is only updated when the input and the output are not equal but it does return the updated output. I guess it shouldn't work like this right?

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: you understand that Hazelcast will make a copy of that value because it needs to go over the line. Also for a local call, you will always get back a copy, never the stored (or inserted) reference.

With this out of the way; I do agree that the code can be cleaned up a bit. There is no reason to return the new instance even if there is no change. It can just as easily return the old instance.

Comment: I agree with you, if it doesn't change it shouldn't update the reference and it might as well return the old instance. What I observed however is that the new instance has changed and it returns the new value but it doesn't update the reference. The reason is that in the IFunction I send I get the BitSet from the old instance, set it on the new instance and then update its values. I do not want to copy it cause it would be too expensive. And by instance I mean a BloomFilter object that is kind of a wrapper around a BitSet and its equals depends on the BitSet equals. Does it make any sense?

Comment: BTW I hope I understand correctly. When you say "Hazelcast will make a copy of that value because it needs to go over the line" you are talking about the return value right? Because I am using a function.

Comment: I'm talking about the return value; but I'm also talking about the inserted value.

e.g.

Person p1 = new Person(); atomicref.set(p1); Person p2 = atomicref.get(); Person p3 = atomicref.get(); p1/p2/p3 wil be different object instances.

Comment: I understand this but the problem I am talking about is different. It doesn't have to do with the get or set but the behavior of the alterAndGet and alter functions. I don't want to set and get every time but I want to send over the line a function and alter the reference which causes the problem I tried to describe above.

Comment: So the bitset equals works based on reference, and not based on content, do I understand that correctly? To be honest, I'm a bit lost in what is going wrong with your code. 

So can you create a unit test of what fails? Code rules.. language sucks.

Comment: Sure, I thought that it would make sense for some reason but a test is better indeed. I will let you know when I have something.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at it this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Issue should be fixed, please see my comment for the related PR you have posted
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/2484

Comment: But now the reference is updated even when it is indeed not changed right? Isn't this a bit inefficient?